# Solr Query - Set a threshold match percentage for my search

Tags: search, solr, threshold

I am using Solr - Lucene 4.0. I am trying to run a query to search a field called Names.

An example of a query would be:

Names:George

When I execute the search with the amount of rows to return to 1000 it returns 1000 results. I expect it to return way less than that. The last results aren't similar at all. Is there a way to set a threshold for my results so that it only returns matches of a certain similarity?

Comment: you could cut off results by using rows param, is it suitable or you wanna some metrics for that?

Answer (score 0):

actually you cant not create a minimum matching score. because the matching score is relative and depends on a lot of things (ex. number of overall documents, number of matching terms found).

i do not know what is your case exactly. but you may consider use paging. like get results in 20 document at a time and check the score of the last document and then stop if its lower than a threshold that you specify.